# Golang package interface

Tags: go

I am bit new to golang and I have a question about packages and interfaces.
If I have package1, that needs to use implementation of an interface that can be swapped in future with other implementation, would that be possible?

some pseudo code

package implementation contains current implementation of interface

```
type TestI interface {
   M1()
}
```

```
package implementation

type Impl struct {}

funct (i *Impl) M1 ( ... do something )
```

```
package package1

import TestI somehow and call M1 method but with flexibility to swap it with other implementation of this interface in future?
```

package package1 should use implementation without knowing about it (something like DI in c# or java, package should only know about interface, and not about implementation)
Where should TestI interface be defined? Sorry if this is a bit confusing, just trying to get my head around it.

This is equivalent in c#

```
ITest {
  SetClass(Class1 cl);
}

// package1
class Class1 {
  private ITest test {get; set;}

  public void SomeMethod() {
// i want to somehow set this in other package
    test.SetClass(this);
  }
}

// package2
class Test implements ITest {
 private Class1 cl;

SetClass(Class1 c) {
 this.c1 = c;
}

}
```

Comment: In Golang for interface implementation, there is no need to use `implements`. You just implement the interface and it is auto-detected. Now regarding how to use `TestI` so that you can swap implementations in the future - You can have the `TestI` defined anywhere. When using the implementation make sure that you are creating `Impl` object and assigning it to `TestI` parameter. That way you are using `TestI` interface everywhere and when you want to swap it's implementation you just create object of type say `Impl2` and assign it to `TestI1` param and the implementation gets changed to new one.

Comment: Consider the advice given in [the wiki](https://github.com/golang/go/wiki/CodeReviewComments#interfaces) "Go interfaces generally belong in the package that uses values of the interface type, not the package that implements those values".

Comment: Hey @SaiRaviTejaK, can you please explain this part: make sure that you are creating Impl object and assigning it to TestI parameter. How is this done in go? 
You mean assigning it to parameter in function? But if there is no function, I just want to use it? This means I need to create a function func Foo() TestI {} that returns interface, and to return Impl instead?
Thanks!

Comment: @user3728390 Basically where ever you want to use `Impl` use `TestI` so in future if you replace concrete type then you need not update all the usages. Also note that functions should return concrete types. But while using the returned values you can assign them to a interface variable.

Comment: What is the question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unless you are writing an interface-first application, it is generally best to write the concrete implementations without declaring any interfaces. Then the users of that package can declare the necessary interfaces. For example:

```
type Implementation struct {
   ...
}

func (i Implementation) FuncA() {...}
func (i Implementation) FuncB() {...}
```

If some type that implements `FuncA` is required, you can declare:

```
type IntfA interface {
   FuncA()
}
```

Any type that has the method `FuncA` implements `IntfA`, and `Implementation`  fits that description, so you can pass an instance of `Implementation` to a function that needs `IntfA`.

Similarly, if you need an interface that has both `FuncA` and `FuncB`, you can declaret:

```
type IntfAB interface {
   FuncA()
   FuncB()
}
```

and `Implementation` also implements `IntfAB`.

So, ideally, you would declare the interface you need where you use it, and any type with a matching set of methods can be used for the implementation of that interface.

If you are writing based on an existing interface, then you can put that interface in a separate package than the implementation, or you can keep the interface and the implementation in the same package, whichever makes more sense for your use case.